# Round the value from 1.035 into 1.04 using javascript round method

Tags: javascript, rounding

`Math.round(2.035*100)/100` here output is showing **2.04 it is correct output** but
`Math.round(1.035*100)/100` here output is showing **1.03 it is wrong output**
where as expected output is 1.04.

Can anybody give me solution for above issue.

Comment: This is due to the limitations of floating point arithmetic ... eg, 0.3 != 0.1 + 0.2 - if you want better results, look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round in the section Example: Decimal rounding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Math.round((2.035*100).toFixed(2))/100 // 2.04
Math.round((1.035*100).toFixed(2))/100 // 1.04
```